# How to use a function that I have written in postgresql in my aspnet core code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

I wrote a function in my postgresql database that returns an array I would like to retrieve its values ​​in my application which is aspnet core c #.

here is the function signature

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Search (source integer, destination integer)
RETURNS table (
Idvoyage integer,
Name1 text,
SourId integer,
DestId integer)
AS $ trip $
```

Comment: Have you looked at Entity Framework Core? It might be overkill for this tiny task, but would be worth your time to learn!

Comment: Maybe this answer can be usefull:
[How to get data from PostgreSQL function in ASP.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081544/how-to-get-data-from-postgresql-function-in-asp-net-core/76964096#76964096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several searches I finally found how to use my function on the same site of stackoverflow but I lost the link but I put the code for people that could help here
"searchforserchticketall" is my function in my database and
 command.Parameters.Add (new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter ("source", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
                {Value = source});
                command.Parameters.Add (new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter ("companyid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer) my two parameters next
command.ExecuteReader () to execute the function

```
  using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                var function = "Transport.";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "searchforserchticketall";
                command.Parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("source", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
                { Value = source });
                command.Parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("compagnieid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
                { Value = compagnieid });
                if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    command.Connection.Open();
                var res = command.ExecuteReader();

            }
```